# "Being industrious" vs. "industriousness"

Tags: adjectives

From [here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1200):

> Despite **my industriousness**, the professor only considered the scores of my final exam.

a:Despite the fact that I was being industrious, the professor only considered the scores of my final exam.

b:Despite my being industrious, the professor only considered the scores of my final exam.
Which one is more natural? Is there any difference between those?

Now, would you  show me what is the difference between a and b?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first probably seems more natural, but that's mostly just personal opinion. I don't think one is any less right than the other, at least in general.

The only difference I can imagine is that "being industrious" could refer to a particular point in time, whereas "industriousness" has a more persistent tone. In other words, the latter infers more of a personality trait, while the former could refer either to that, or to a quality at one instant in time.

It's a similar ambiguity to "I was eating steak." In this example, the speaker could either be referring to a particular point in time when he was actively consuming steak, or it could refer to a time before he became a vegetarian.

That all said, one's quality of "industriousness" is unlikely to vary greatly over time, so that ambiguity is similarly unlikely to be confusing. So long story short, either is correct, but I think "industriousness" sounds a bit better.